# What is the name of the chemical compound: Cr(CO3)3?

Tags: nomenclature, ionic-compounds

### Cr(CO${_3}$)${}_3$

This is an ionic compound. Chromium is a transition metal cation and CO${_3}$ is an anion with a charge of 2-, as said in my chemistry textbook.

And *since* CO${_3}$ has a charge of 2-, the over all charge of CO${_3}$ would be 6-, since it has a subscript of 3 in the **bolded** formula above. So my guess is that since Chromium has no such subscript, its charge would automatically be 6-, which should be right because it would cancel out both charges.

Therefore it would be Chromium (VI) Carbonate? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Fairly sure this thing doesn't exist to begin with - it would immediately decompose to $\ce{CrO3 + 3CO2}$.

Comment: Scifinder agrees with @ortho. The only compound with the molecular formula $\ce{C3CrO9}$ to be found is tricarbonatochromate(III).

Comment: I'm quite sure you have a typo there and if it's not supposed to be 'am I right" question, you should take this to mind - it may be CrCO3 but not this. even if compound with your formula existed it wouldn't be ionic, but covalent.

Comment: Honestly I think even the Cr(III) compound $\ce{Cr2(CO3)3}$ doesn't exist. The aluminium and iron(III) carbonates certainly don't. With that said I'd presume this is just a nomenclature exercise and the question setter just didn't bother thinking twice about whether the compound was realistic or not.

Comment: @orthocresol Well, at least chromium(III) carbonate [seems to exist](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-6031(84)87107-5).

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/63442/what-is-the-name-of-the-chemical-compound-crco33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close. The chromium will have a 6+ charge (not 6-). I suspect this may have been a typo, because you are right in understanding the need to cancel out charges to generate an overall neutral molecule.

The only other correction is that there is no need to capitalise. So, the correct name is chromium(VI) carbonate.

Comment: The correct name, *if it existed*.

Comment: Actually, the correct name, regardless of whether it exists or not. Even [hypothetical chemical compounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Hypothetical_chemical_compounds) need to have correct names. Nothing in this question asked about validity of the compound. [Nitrogen pentafluoride](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00051a027) needs a name whether it exists or not.